# How to keep bootstrap switch tunrd off for the first time?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using [Bootstrap Switch](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/) for one of my projects. If my checkbox is not checked, the switch is first appearing as on and do a quick movement to off instead of staying off from the beginning. I don't understand how to resolve this issue. In the demo it looks like working fine. But when the check box is checked, it works as expected.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-switch.min.css" />
<script src="bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script>

<input id="mode_selector" type="checkbox" data-size="small" data-on-text="live" data-off-text="test" >
<script> $("#mode_selector").bootstrapSwitch(); </script>
```

Comment: Could you provide some HTML/JS code that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want the initial value of the checkbox to be `off`.

I think this should work:

```
<input id="mode_selector" type="checkbox" ... checked=false>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the initializing code in `document.ready`

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#mode_selector").bootstrapSwitch();        
  }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check various option for bootstrap switch [here](http://bootstrapswitch.com/options.html)

During your initialization you can change the state of the **checkbox** to **false**
`$('#mode_selector').bootstrapSwitch('state',true);`

Answer (score 0):

This will init a checkbox to ON:

`<input id="mode_selector" type="checkbox" ... checked='checked'>`
or
`<input id="mode_selector" type="checkbox" ... checked>`

This will init a checkbox to OFF:

`<input id="mode_selector" type="checkbox">`

Just remove the `checked` attribute completely